# getting error while integrating map in android application

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to integrate map in my android application. I have generated key through sh1 and using package name. but when I use map activity then it will give error. I have also installed google play service. but it cannot resolve on map callback activity.
It does not support even android:name in xml file

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

And My `Manifest.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.user.myapplication" >

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAz-m0JHQmk0qqairiEkkKFaiccgzTxb10"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: it also does not support android name in xml file

Comment: android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

Comment: I think you should read the documentation, because there are a lot of ways to implement a map, but hopefully Google still proposes the best way: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Comment: post your manifest file also @narendra pandey

Comment: Would you please specify the type of error ...

Comment: basically it does not take onmapreadycallback and google map. as it specify that it cannot resolve symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.myapplication" >
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your key"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Manifest file` has should be like this.

Source [click here!](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" > 
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.user.myapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="12"
  android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
  android:name="com.example.user.myapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.
  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.
  ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true" />

<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <activity
     android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >

     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>

  </activity>

  <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyDKymeBXNeiFWY5jRUejv6zItpmr2MVyQ0" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your manifest file. `<uses-permssion>` tag comes out side of the `<application>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.myapplication" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAz-m0JHQmk0qqairiEkkKFaiccgzTxb10"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: but why there is error in xml and java file saying that google map cannot resolve. onmapreadycallback does not resolve. even i installed google play service and google repository what to install next.